# How to get and set a persistent variable server side in a web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to save a simple int on the server side then any user can log in and update it. I thought this would be a simple task and began trying to use the settings designer however i couldn't change the scope from "application" to "user" as application settings are read only.

I know i could save and change the variable in an XML file but i thought there must be a more simple way.

I have tried to use user profiles, however it isn't working any ideas? (I have also used Context.Profile.)

```
<profile>
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
  </providers>
  <properties>
    <add name="FilmNumber" type="int" allowAnonymous="true" defaultValue="2"/>
  </properties>
</profile>
```

Code:

```
//********Get poster Number*******
int LastPosterNumber=0;
LastPosterNumber = (int)HttpContext.Current.Profile.GetPropertyValue("FilmNumber");

string strFileName;
strFileName = FileField.PostedFile.FileName;
string c = (LastPosterNumber + 1).ToString();
string dirPath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~") + "/Images/FilmPosters/" + c + ".jpg";
FileField.PostedFile.SaveAs(dirPath);

//******Save new poster number*******
HttpContext.Current.Profile.SetPropertyValue("FilmNumber", int.Parse(c));
HttpContext.Current.Profile.Save();
```

Comment: Define "persistent" - is this int a variable used during the user's session, or are you trying to let a user change a config value?

Comment: Are you interested in making Profiles working or simply storing some per-session data (`Session` object would make more sense in later case).

Comment: I'm trying to let the user change a config value. Basically this value will be the number of the last uploaded image so that the next uploaded image number will be +1 of the last. So the number will stay even when the users session is expired.

Comment: You probably should not save this info at all - cache it application wide or better yet scan all files to find next free number. Don't forget about multiple users doing uploads if you care.

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid Settings because they require your config file to be modifiable, also the concept of "user settings" in ASP.NET does not exist because the application always runs under the user context of W3C's worker process - the .NET Settings API is not aware of ASP.NET Membership or other concepts of "Users".

Your best option is to use a DBMS, `Application` state or a static field in your application (if it doesn't need to be persisted beyond the lifespan of `w3wp.exe`) or a file on disk, you don't have to use XML serialization, you can write it out manually (just be sure to lock the file first because ASP.NET applications are multi-threaded).

In my applications, I only store the connection string and the bare minimum of initialization settings in `web.config`, per-user settings I store in a database table and write a simple API layer for this (usually with application-settings and inheritance or "`EffectiveSettings`"). Note that this is completely different (as far as the implementation is concerned) from .NET's Settings API which I avoid completely for various reasons, including those already promulgated in this answer.

#### Notes on IIS w3wp.exe lifespan:

IIS will terminate or "recycle" w3wp.exe at any time for a variety of reasons, which is why your ASP.NET application must persist to long-term storage at the nearest opportunity and any in-memory state will be lost. Reasons for this include:

- Inactivity. If an application pool worker process has not handled a request in at least 45 minutes (or so) IIS will shut down the process.
- Recycling. IIS takes pre-emptive measures against worker processes leaking resources by terminating and restarting them every 90 minutes or so (or it might be 29 hours, I'm not sure).
- Unresponsiveness. IIS gives worker processes a strict timeout to respond to incoming requests, I think the default is 60 seconds. If no response is sent to the client then the process will be restarted.
- Reaching a memory limit. Similar to the automatic time-based recycling described above, IIS will restart a worker process if it reaches a memory limit (which is why it's important to manage your resources).
- Reaching a request limit. Again, similar to the automatic time-based recycling, IIS will restart a worker process after its odometer reads X many requests. This is disabled by default but your ISP might have enabled it.

Comment: What is the lifespan on w3wp.exe? this integer cannot be lost. If it is lost it wrecks the chain of images and the page will call the wrong images if it reset/lost.

Comment: I've updated my answer with information on w3wp.exe lifespan.

Comment: I need something more permanent. Maybe writing it to a database or an XML file is the only answer. It is a shared value with all users. I thought there would be a more simple way to store a constant variable. Not that writing it to a database or XML is difficult it just seems like it would be more labor intensive for the application and require more coding.